# Recover 2.7TB partition converted from GPT to MBR

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, mbr

I have a 3TB disk which had a 128MB Microsoft basic data partition at the beginning, and the rest was a large ~2.7TB ntfs partition. I recently converted this disk from GPT to MBR, and the second large partition is now invisible in gdisk. I have read that MBR cannot handle partitions over 2.2TB, so I imagine when I converted the disk, the large 2.7TB partition was lost in some way.

Is it possible to recover this partition?

When I load gdisk on this drive I get the error message

> Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in
>   memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by typing 'q'
>   if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions to GPT format!

From this message I gathered that the disk will simply be converted to GPT with existing data being kept in tact normally. However typing w gives this message

> Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE
>   EXISTING PARTITIONS!!

which suggests that data on the drive will be lost.

Is it possible to covert this disk back to GPT whilst keeping the data on it?

Comment: Even if you mess up terribly, there’s a very good chance. Knowing the original disk layout, you could try and find the beginning of the second partition manually using `hexdump` or the like.

Comment: I would just convert it back;  Why did you convert it knowing there was a MBR limit?

Comment: I didn't know about the MBR limit at the time.

Answer (score -1):

First, take an image (yep, I know that you will need another 3TB disk, but it would be great, if you handle image, not the disk itself)

Many times I've recovered hard drives with "Active@ Partition Recover". No ads, it is really great software! Give a try.